# Check if logged in on ios facebook sdk 3.0

Tags: ios, cocoa, facebook-graph-api, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using iOS facebook SDK 3.0. How can i check if the user is already logged in?

I tried the line below but it does not work properly. It **sometimes** returns NO although I am logged in. Any suggestions?

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen == YES)
{
  // post to wall else login
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

this is how I open my Facebook session:

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_likes", 
                        @"read_stream",
                        @"publish_actions",
                        nil];
return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                      allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState state,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                         state:state
                                                         error:error];
                                 }];
```

The first time it needs login and so it works. If i try this while I am already logged in the FBSession.activeSession.isOpen returns NO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check if you have a valid token by trying to open a new session without allowing the 
 login UI

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    // post to wall
} else {
    // try to open session with existing valid token
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    if([FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
        // post to wall
    } else {
        // you need to log the user
    }
}
```

Comment: Just sends me to authenticate every single time. How do you force the sdk to retain the auth token? Permissions match app but FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded is the state.

Comment: This answer does not work and has issues with the system account versus tokens obtained via the Facebook app or UIWebView

Comment: @PsychoDad The question is for Facebook sdk 3.0

Answer (score 10):

If you are using FBSDK greater then 4.x then there is no concept of FBSession. You have to find the active session only by using `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` simply check if it has `nil` value, no active session else it is.

> Instead, you should check `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` at
>   `viewDidLoad` or similar. If a `current token` is available, do the
>   post-login work. You can also use `currentAccessToken` to retrieve
>   cached tokens.

you can find more here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x

> `FBSession.activeSession` has been replaced with `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` and `FBSDKLoginManager`. There is no concept of
>   `session state`. Instead, use the manager to login and this sets the
>   `currentAccessToken` reference.

Answer (score 9):

i did it as in the Facebook example

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
{

}
```

Comment: I am not so sure about this. session.state appears to now be a bit mask. you can also have FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended state. there is a comment about a session state open bit: Open session state indicating user has logged in or a cached token is available. I think an == compare would not work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

The session is active if the state is either in `FBSessionStateOpen` or in `FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended`. You can use the function below to check if the user is logged in:

```
- (BOOL)isSessionOpen
{
    return FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you opening your FBSession?

If you're creating an instance, be sure to set FBSession.activeSession. That was my issue for a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) 
{
   NSLog(@"Already login");
    //[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI: YES];
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking answers will be better received if they explain why/how they work instead of just throwing out some code.